# java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: cannot encode with codec: CODEC_ID_MP3

Tags: java, video, webcam-capture

i am running this simple sample from lib WebCam-capture with no success.Here is my code and below it i describe the exception problem

```
File file = new File("output.ts");

        IMediaWriter writer = ToolFactory.makeWriter(file.getName());
        Dimension size = WebcamResolution.QVGA.getSize();

        writer.addVideoStream(0, 0, ICodec.ID.CODEC_ID_H264, size.width, size.height);

        Webcam webcam = Webcam.getDefault();
        webcam.setViewSize(size);
        webcam.open(true);

        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        for (int i = 0; i < 50; i++) {

            System.out.println("Capture frame " + i);

            BufferedImage image = ConverterFactory.convertToType(webcam.getImage(), BufferedImage.TYPE_3BYTE_BGR);
            IConverter converter = ConverterFactory.createConverter(image, IPixelFormat.Type.YUV420P);

            IVideoPicture frame = converter.toPicture(image, (System.currentTimeMillis() - start) * 1000);
            frame.setKeyFrame(i == 0);
            frame.setQuality(0);

            writer.encodeVideo(0, frame);

            // 10 FPS
            Thread.sleep(100);
        }

        writer.close();

        System.out.println("Video recorded in file: " + file.getAbsolutePath());
```

Here is the exception why is this happened and how i can solve it?

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: cannot encode with codec: CODEC_ID_H264
    at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaWriter.addVideoStream(MediaWriter.java:440)
    at com.xuggle.mediatool.MediaWriter.addVideoStream(MediaWriter.java:430)
    at com.panos.WebCamRecorder.vRecorder(WebCamRecorder.java:80)
    at com.panos.App.main(App.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the build of Xuggler (the Java FFmpeg wrapper you are using in your code) that you are using does not support encoding with mp3 audio or with H.264 video. It looks like you're using an LGPL build. With an LGPL build of Xuggler you can only "Decode" those codecs. To do encoding, you'll need a version of Xuggler that wraps an FFmpeg build supporting those decoders.

Here are the codecs supported by a build without enabling GPL and non-free (D means it can decode, E means it can encode). Be sure to search through the whole list as there are duplicate entries for decoding and encoding:

```
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO  E  id=CODEC_ID_FLASHSV name=flashsv
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_LOCO    name=loco
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_XAN_WC3 name=xan_wc3
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_QCELP   name=qcelp
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO  E  id=CODEC_ID_ADPCM_G722  name=g722
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_BINTEXT name=bintext
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_ESCAPE130   name=escape130
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO  E  id=CODEC_ID_ROQ name=roqvideo
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_UTVIDEO name=utvideo
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_WMAPRO  name=wmapro
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_BMV_AUDIO   name=bmv_audio
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_PCM_S16LE_PLANAR    name=pcm_s16le_planar
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO  E  id=CODEC_ID_PRORES  name=prores_anatoliy
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_AURA    name=aura
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO  E  id=CODEC_ID_TARGA   name=targa
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_INDEO2  name=indeo2
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_ZMBV    name=zmbv
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO  E  id=CODEC_ID_PCM_S8  name=pcm_s8
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_ADPCM_XA    name=adpcm_xa
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO  E  id=CODEC_ID_G723_1  name=g723_1
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_FRWU    name=frwu
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_MPEG2VIDEO  name=mpegvideo
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_WMV3    name=wmv3
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_ADPCM_IMA_AMV   name=adpcm_ima_amv
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_SHORTEN name=shorten
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_ROQ name=roqvideo
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO  E  id=CODEC_ID_GIF name=gif
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO  E  id=CODEC_ID_WMAV2   name=wmav2
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO  E  id=CODEC_ID_WMV1    name=wmv1
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO  E  id=CODEC_ID_MP2 name=mp2
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_SOL_DPCM    name=sol_dpcm
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_JPEGLS  name=jpegls
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_QPEG    name=qpeg
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_VP6 name=vp6
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_AAC name=aac
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_PCM_S24DAUD name=pcm_s24daud
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_MACE6   name=mace6
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_ADPCM_IMA_WAV   name=adpcm_ima_wav
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_SUBTITLE  D   id=CODEC_ID_SRT name=srt
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO  E  id=CODEC_ID_DVVIDEO name=dvvideo
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_MDEC    name=mdec
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_SMC name=smc
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_ADPCM_IMA_APC   name=adpcm_ima_apc
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO  E  id=CODEC_ID_SONIC_LS    name=sonicls
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO  E  id=CODEC_ID_PGM name=pgm
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_8SVX_EXP    name=8svx_exp
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO  E  id=CODEC_ID_PCM_ALAW    name=pcm_alaw
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_WMV1    name=wmv1
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_FFWAVESYNTH name=wavesynth
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO  E  id=CODEC_ID_FIRST_AUDIO name=pcm_s16le
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO  E  id=CODEC_ID_VP8 name=libvpx
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO  E  id=CODEC_ID_DPX name=dpx
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO  E  id=CODEC_ID_A64_MULTI   name=a64multi
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_MMVIDEO name=mmvideo
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_WS_VQA  name=vqavideo
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_MLP name=mlp
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO  E  id=CODEC_ID_PCM_S24BE   name=pcm_s24be
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO  E  id=CODEC_ID_WMAV1   name=wmav1
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_XBM name=xbm
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_INDEO5  name=indeo5
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO  E  id=CODEC_ID_R210    name=r210
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_AVRP    name=avrp
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_VMNC    name=vmnc
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_AMR_WB  name=amrwb
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_ADPCM_G726  name=g726
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_ADPCM_IMA_WS    name=adpcm_ima_ws
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_VP6F    name=vp6f
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_4XM name=4xm
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_PCX name=pcx
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO  E  id=CODEC_ID_EAC3    name=eac3
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_ROQ_DPCM    name=roq_dpcm
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_SUBTITLE  D   id=CODEC_ID_FIRST_SUBTITLE  name=dvdsub
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_MAD name=eamad
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO  E  id=CODEC_ID_ASV1    name=asv1
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO  E  id=CODEC_ID_MSMPEG4V2   name=msmpeg4v2
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_TRUEMOTION2 name=truemotion2
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO  E  id=CODEC_ID_PCM_F32LE   name=pcm_f32le
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_MACE3   name=mace3
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_PCM_U24BE   name=pcm_u24be
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO  E  id=CODEC_ID_AAC name=aac
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_INDEO3  name=indeo3
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_DFA name=dfa
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO  E  id=CODEC_ID_MJPEG   name=mjpeg
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_V210X   name=v210x
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO  E  id=CODEC_ID_PCM_S32LE   name=pcm_s32le
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_ADPCM_THP   name=adpcm_thp
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_DSICINAUDIO name=dsicinaudio
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_WNV1    name=wnv1
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_FRAPS   name=fraps
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_PTX name=ptx
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_MUSEPACK8   name=mpc8
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_PCM_S8  name=pcm_s8
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_SUBTITLE  D   id=CODEC_ID_DVB_SUBTITLE    name=dvbsub
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_FFV1    name=ffv1
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_ASV1    name=asv1
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_TSCC    name=camtasia
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_VORBIS  name=vorbis
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO  E  id=CODEC_ID_AC3 name=ac3
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO  E  id=CODEC_ID_PCM_S32BE   name=pcm_s32be
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_PRORES  name=prores
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_JPEG2000    name=j2k
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_ANSI    name=ansi
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_TARGA   name=targa
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_PCM_U16BE   name=pcm_u16be
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO  E  id=CODEC_ID_ADPCM_YAMAHA    name=adpcm_yamaha
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO  E  id=CODEC_ID_RA_144  name=real_144
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO  E  id=CODEC_ID_PNG name=png
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO  E  id=CODEC_ID_Y41P    name=y41p
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_SVQ1    name=svq1
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_PRORES  name=prores_lgpl
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_H263I   name=h263i
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_VIXL    name=xl
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_AMR_NB  name=amrnb
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_FIRST_AUDIO name=pcm_s16le
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_ADPCM_MS    name=adpcm_ms
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_IDF name=idf
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO  E  id=CODEC_ID_CLJR    name=cljr
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO  E  id=CODEC_ID_FLV1    name=flv
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_MSZH    name=mszh
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_VMDVIDEO    name=vmdvideo
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_IMC name=imc
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_ADPCM_G722  name=g722
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_DPX name=dpx
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_CINEPAK name=cinepak
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO  E  id=CODEC_ID_MSMPEG4V3   name=msmpeg4
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO  E  id=CODEC_ID_V410    name=v410
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_PCM_F32BE   name=pcm_f32be
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO  E  id=CODEC_ID_SONIC   name=sonic
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_PCM_F64BE   name=pcm_f64be
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_INTERPLAY_VIDEO name=interplayvideo
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_QTRLE   name=qtrle
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_VB  name=vb
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_ZLIB    name=zlib
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO  E  id=CODEC_ID_PCM_U24LE   name=pcm_u24le
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_TTA name=tta
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_ADPCM_SWF   name=adpcm_swf
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO  E  id=CODEC_ID_AMR_NB  name=libopencore_amrnb
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO  E  id=CODEC_ID_FFVHUFF name=ffvhuff
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO  E  id=CODEC_ID_LJPEG   name=ljpeg
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_SNOW    name=snow
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_MP1 name=mp1float
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO  E  id=CODEC_ID_PCM_F64LE   name=pcm_f64le
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_VC1IMAGE    name=vc1image
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_FLIC    name=flic
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_CLJR    name=cljr
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_PNG name=png
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_PCM_F32LE   name=pcm_f32le
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_FLAC    name=flac
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_SUBTITLE  D   id=CODEC_ID_HDMV_PGS_SUBTITLE   name=pgssub
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_ADPCM_ADX   name=adpcm_adx
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO  E  id=CODEC_ID_XBM name=xbm
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO  E  id=CODEC_ID_JPEG2000    name=j2k
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO  E  id=CODEC_ID_A64_MULTI5  name=a64multi5
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_R10K    name=r10k
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_VC1 name=vc1
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_PCM_S16BE   name=pcm_s16be
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO  E  id=CODEC_ID_ADPCM_IMA_QT    name=adpcm_ima_qt
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_RA_288  name=real_288
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_TGV name=eatgv
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_MSMPEG4V2   name=msmpeg4v2
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_WMV2    name=wmv2
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_COOK    name=cook
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO  E  id=CODEC_ID_PCM_U32LE   name=pcm_u32le
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_DSICINVIDEO name=dsicinvideo
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO  E  id=CODEC_ID_RV10    name=rv10
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO  E  id=CODEC_ID_AC3 name=ac3_fixed
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_ADPCM_EA_R2 name=adpcm_ea_r2
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_RPZA    name=rpza
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_VP6A    name=vp6a
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_EXR name=exr
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_ANM name=anm
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_MJPEGB  name=mjpegb
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_EAC3    name=eac3
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_SPEEX   name=libspeex
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_INTERPLAY_DPCM  name=interplay_dpcm
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_WESTWOOD_SND1   name=ws_snd1
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO  E  id=CODEC_ID_MPEG1VIDEO  name=mpeg1video
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_IFF_ILBM    name=iff_ilbm
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_VBLE    name=vble
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_YUV4    name=yuv4
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_PCM_U32BE   name=pcm_u32be
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_MP3ADU  name=mp3adu
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_ADPCM_IMA_QT    name=adpcm_ima_qt
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO  E  id=CODEC_ID_AAC name=libvo_aacenc
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO  E  id=CODEC_ID_PCX name=pcx
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO  E  id=CODEC_ID_FLAC    name=flac
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO  E  id=CODEC_ID_PCM_U24BE   name=pcm_u24be
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_V210    name=v210
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_DXA name=dxa
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_TXD name=txd
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO  E  id=CODEC_ID_BMP name=bmp
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_WAVPACK name=wavpack
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_SONIC   name=sonic
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_ADPCM_4XM   name=adpcm_4xm
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO  E  id=CODEC_ID_FFV1    name=ffv1
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_PAM name=pam
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_INDEO4  name=indeo4
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_MSMPEG4V3   name=msmpeg4
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_BMP name=bmp
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_RV20    name=rv20
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO  E  id=CODEC_ID_ADPCM_G726  name=g726
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO  E  id=CODEC_ID_ADPCM_MS    name=adpcm_ms
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_TRUESPEECH  name=truespeech
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_ZEROCODEC   name=zerocodec
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO  E  id=CODEC_ID_FLASHSV2    name=flashsv2
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_PPM name=ppm
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_V408    name=v408
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_BINKAUDIO_DCT   name=binkaudio_dct
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_ADPCM_EA_XAS    name=adpcm_ea_xas
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_DVVIDEO name=dvvideo
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_CAVS    name=cavs
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_RV40    name=rv40
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO  E  id=CODEC_ID_PCM_F32BE   name=pcm_f32be
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_MP3ON4  name=mp3on4float
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_PCM_S24LE   name=pcm_s24le
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_PGMYUV  name=pgmyuv
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_DNXHD   name=dnxhd
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO  E  id=CODEC_ID_ASV2    name=asv2
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_RAWVIDEO    name=rawvideo
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_VP3 name=vp3
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_ATRAC1  name=atrac1
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_PCM_U8  name=pcm_u8
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_SUBTITLE  D   id=CODEC_ID_SSA name=ass
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_IDCIN   name=idcinvideo
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO  E  id=CODEC_ID_MPEG4   name=mpeg4
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_CDXL    name=cdxl
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_Y41P    name=y41p
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO  E  id=CODEC_ID_SVQ1    name=svq1
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_PCM_F64LE   name=pcm_f64le
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO  E  id=CODEC_ID_NELLYMOSER  name=nellymoser
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_QDRAW   name=qdraw
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_TQI name=eatqi
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO  E  id=CODEC_ID_V308    name=v308
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO  E  id=CODEC_ID_ALAC    name=alac
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_PCM_U24LE   name=pcm_u24le
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_SUBTITLE  D   id=CODEC_ID_XSUB    name=xsub
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_DXTORY  name=dxtory
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO  E  id=CODEC_ID_R10K    name=r10k
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO  E  id=CODEC_ID_AMV name=amv
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_THP name=thp
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_MP2 name=mp2float
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_PCM_BLURAY  name=pcm_bluray
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO  E  id=CODEC_ID_ROQ_DPCM    name=roq_dpcm
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_YOP name=yop
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_HUFFYUV name=huffyuv
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_BFI name=bfi
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_MPEG2VIDEO  name=mpeg2video
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO  E  id=CODEC_ID_TIFF    name=tiff
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_PCM_S32LE   name=pcm_s32le
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO  E  id=CODEC_ID_ADPCM_SWF   name=adpcm_swf
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_SUBTITLE   E  id=CODEC_ID_XSUB    name=xsub
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_NELLYMOSER  name=nellymoser
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_WMV3IMAGE   name=wmv3image
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_FFVHUFF name=ffvhuff
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO  E  id=CODEC_ID_RAWVIDEO    name=rawvideo
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_AC3 name=ac3
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_ADPCM_EA_MAXIS_XA   name=adpcm_ea_maxis_xa
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_RL2 name=rl2
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_CMV name=eacmv
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_VP5 name=vp5
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_SMACKAUDIO  name=smackaud
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_PCM_DVD name=pcm_dvd
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_PCM_ZORK    name=pcm_zork
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO  E  id=CODEC_ID_XWD name=xwd
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_IFF_BYTERUN1    name=iff_byterun1
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_CYUV    name=cyuv
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_PGM name=pgm
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_V410    name=v410
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO  E  id=CODEC_ID_PCM_U32BE   name=pcm_u32be
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO  E  id=CODEC_ID_ADPCM_IMA_WAV   name=adpcm_ima_wav
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_XBIN    name=xbin
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_RA_144  name=real_144
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO  E  id=CODEC_ID_V408    name=v408
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO  E  id=CODEC_ID_MSVIDEO1    name=msvideo1
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_ADPCM_EA_R3 name=adpcm_ea_r3
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_MP1 name=mp1
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO  E  id=CODEC_ID_SGI name=sgi
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO  E  id=CODEC_ID_H263    name=h263
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO  E  id=CODEC_ID_PBM name=pbm
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_ATRAC3  name=atrac3
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO  E  id=CODEC_ID_PCM_S24DAUD name=pcm_s24daud
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_WMAV2   name=wmav2
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_SUBTITLE   E  id=CODEC_ID_FIRST_SUBTITLE  name=dvdsub
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_BINKVIDEO   name=binkvideo
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_RV30    name=rv30
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_PICTOR  name=pictor
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_VMDAUDIO    name=vmdaudio
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO  E  id=CODEC_ID_PCM_MULAW   name=pcm_mulaw
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_ADPCM_SBPRO_2   name=adpcm_sbpro_2
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_AASC    name=aasc
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_LAGARITH    name=lagarith
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_G723_1  name=g723_1
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO  E  id=CODEC_ID_PCM_S16BE   name=pcm_s16be
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_SUNRAST name=sunrast
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_H263    name=h263
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_THEORA  name=theora
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO  E  id=CODEC_ID_PRORES  name=prores
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_BINKAUDIO_RDFT  name=binkaudio_rdft
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO  E  id=CODEC_ID_PCM_F64BE   name=pcm_f64be
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO  E  id=CODEC_ID_SPEEX   name=libspeex
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_DIRAC   name=dirac
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_C93 name=c93
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_SGI name=sgi
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO  E  id=CODEC_ID_PRORES  name=prores_kostya
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_PCM_S32BE   name=pcm_s32be
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_SIPR    name=sipr
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO  E  id=CODEC_ID_HUFFYUV name=huffyuv
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_ASV2    name=asv2
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_NUV name=nuv
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_SVQ3    name=svq3
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_PCM_S8_PLANAR   name=pcm_s8_planar
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_MP3ON4  name=mp3on4
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_FLASHSV name=flashsv
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_TMV name=tmv
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_MUSEPACK7   name=mpc7
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_PCM_U16LE   name=pcm_u16le
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_MPEG1VIDEO  name=mpeg1video
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_KMVC    name=kmvc
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_TGQ name=eatgq
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_BMV_VIDEO   name=bmv_video
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_MP3 name=mp3
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_ADPCM_CT    name=adpcm_ct
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_PCM_ALAW    name=pcm_alaw
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO  E  id=CODEC_ID_WMV2    name=wmv2
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_PBM name=pbm
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_AURA2   name=aura2
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_KGV1    name=kgv1
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO  E  id=CODEC_ID_SNOW    name=snow
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_XAN_WC4 name=xan_wc4
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_QDM2    name=qdm2
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_ADPCM_IMA_DK4   name=adpcm_ima_dk4
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_ADPCM_IMA_SMJPEG    name=adpcm_ima_smjpeg
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_8BPS    name=8bps
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_ULTI    name=ultimotion
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO  E  id=CODEC_ID_QTRLE   name=qtrle
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_DTS name=dca
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_XAN_DPCM    name=xan_dpcm
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_SUBTITLE   E  id=CODEC_ID_DVB_SUBTITLE    name=dvbsub
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_V308    name=v308
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_MIMIC   name=mimic
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO  E  id=CODEC_ID_H261    name=h261
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_CDGRAPHICS  name=cdgraphics
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_MP3 name=mp3float
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO  E  id=CODEC_ID_PCM_U16LE   name=pcm_u16le
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_SUBTITLE   E  id=CODEC_ID_SRT name=srt
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_WMAV1   name=wmav1
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_MOTIONPIXELS    name=motionpixels
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO  E  id=CODEC_ID_H263P   name=h263p
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_AVS name=avs
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_TRUEMOTION1 name=truemotion1
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_RALF    name=ralf
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO  E  id=CODEC_ID_ZMBV    name=zmbv
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_ADPCM_IMA_EA_EACS   name=adpcm_ima_ea_eacs
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_ADPCM_IMA_EA_SEAD   name=adpcm_ima_ea_sead
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_ESCAPE124   name=escape124
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO  E  id=CODEC_ID_V210    name=v210
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_MSVIDEO1    name=msvideo1
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_ALAC    name=alac
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO  E  id=CODEC_ID_PCM_U16BE   name=pcm_u16be
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO  E  id=CODEC_ID_VORBIS  name=libvorbis
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_H261    name=h261
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_MSRLE   name=msrle
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO  E  id=CODEC_ID_RV20    name=rv20
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_MP4ALS  name=als
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_ADPCM_EA    name=adpcm_ea
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO  E  id=CODEC_ID_VORBIS  name=vorbis
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO  E  id=CODEC_ID_PGMYUV  name=pgmyuv
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_BETHSOFTVID name=bethsoftvid
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_VCR1    name=vcr1
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_XWD name=xwd
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_PCM_LXF name=pcm_lxf
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_TWINVQ  name=twinvq
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_ADPCM_IMA_ISS   name=adpcm_ima_iss
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_TIERTEXSEQVIDEO name=tiertexseqvideo
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_H264    name=h264
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO  E  id=CODEC_ID_MPEG2VIDEO  name=mpeg2video
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO  E  id=CODEC_ID_AVRP    name=avrp
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_PCM_U32LE   name=pcm_u32le
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_ADPCM_YAMAHA    name=adpcm_yamaha
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_AMR_WB  name=libopencore_amrwb
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_GSM name=gsm
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO  E  id=CODEC_ID_YUV4    name=yuv4
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_8SVX_FIB    name=8svx_fib
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_MJPEG   name=mjpeg
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_SP5X    name=sp5x
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_TRUEHD  name=truehd
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_ADPCM_IMA_DK3   name=adpcm_ima_dk3
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_SUBTITLE   E  id=CODEC_ID_SSA name=ass
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_FLASHSV2    name=flashsv2
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_CSCD    name=camstudio
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_RV10    name=rv10
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_MPEG4   name=mpeg4
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_G729    name=g729
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO  E  id=CODEC_ID_PCM_U8  name=pcm_u8
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_AMR_NB  name=libopencore_amrnb
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_WMAVOICE    name=wmavoice
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO  E  id=CODEC_ID_SUNRAST name=sunrast
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_JV  name=jv
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_MXPEG   name=mxpeg
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_AYUV    name=ayuv
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO  E  id=CODEC_ID_DTS name=dca
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_PCM_MULAW   name=pcm_mulaw
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_ADPCM_SBPRO_3   name=adpcm_sbpro_3
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_VP8 name=libvpx
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_AAC_LATM    name=aac_latm
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_SMACKVIDEO  name=smackvid
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_MSMPEG4V1   name=msmpeg4v1
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO  E  id=CODEC_ID_DNXHD   name=dnxhd
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_APE name=ape
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_PCM_S24BE   name=pcm_s24be
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_MP2 name=mp2
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO  E  id=CODEC_ID_AYUV    name=ayuv
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO  E  id=CODEC_ID_ADPCM_ADX   name=adpcm_adx
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_WMALOSSLESS name=wmalossless
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_S302M   name=s302m
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_GIF name=gif
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO  E  id=CODEC_ID_PAM name=pam
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO  E  id=CODEC_ID_ZLIB    name=zlib
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO  E  id=CODEC_ID_JPEGLS  name=jpegls
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_AMV name=amv
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_R210    name=r210
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_VP8 name=vp8
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_GSM_MS  name=gsm_ms
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_ADPCM_EA_R1 name=adpcm_ea_r1
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_ADPCM_SBPRO_4   name=adpcm_sbpro_4
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO  E  id=CODEC_ID_THEORA  name=libtheora
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_TIFF    name=tiff
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO D   id=CODEC_ID_FLV1    name=flv
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO D   id=CODEC_ID_MP3ADU  name=mp3adufloat
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_AUDIO  E  id=CODEC_ID_PCM_S24LE   name=pcm_s24le
Codec type=CODEC_TYPE_VIDEO  E  id=CODEC_ID_PPM name=ppm
```